# Error in query (1064): Syntax error near

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is my table:

```
mysql> describe translation;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_translation | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_lang        | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| key            | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| translation    | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| domain         | varchar(80) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| theme          | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And this is my insert:

```
INSERT INTO translation(id_lang,key,translation,domain,theme)
VALUES (2,'Get our latest news and special sales','Rebeu les darreres notícies i ofertes','ShopThemeGlobal','classic');
```

Comment: Syntax error near what? The suspense is killing me!

Comment: Please include what is happening, and what you expect to happen

Comment: Key is a mysql reserved keyword. You need to place backticks around key

Comment: A better idea is to not use reserved words as table/column identifiers.